# Invalid GeoJSON polygons, lots of bow ties

Tags: geojson

I've been trying to figure out what is exactly going on with this GeoJSON polygon. What might be the underlying cause? The output is in GeoJSON, however, it's obviously invalid GeoJSON. I *think* it might be TopoJSON which has been badly converted.

I'm keen to understand what might have generated it and maybe there's a chance to reverse the problem. Until now, I've just used shapely's buffer tool but I figured it's worth reaching out as recent versions of geos/shapely/buffer easily consume 10GB+ to process a tiny file.

So - do you know what might cause this? And any options to reverse this problem?

[image: Bad geojson]

GeoJSON: https://pastebin.com/MmkpHYRD
(Way too many characters to paste :))

Comment: At a guess, the coordinates are out of order for some reason.

Comment: Is there any particular source from where you got this file from? Or is it the result of conversion from the different GIS formats?

Comment: Thank you! I think I've managed to crack what is going on, will write up my result in more detail shortly. I think the underlying data is being transformed incorrectly - converted from EPSG3857 via pyproj.Transformer.from_proj rather than pyproj.Transformer.from_crs. Just validating that's actually what's happening.